# Jquery <Canvas> Draw Several Image

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and i have a form that searches for records in the database and returns a list of records to another page. However the data that is returned draws images on  tag. Only the first image is drawn on the form and the rest isn't. I know this has to do with closure in loop in jquery but how can i overcome it here.

Made some edits to the jscript however only the first image is been displayed on all canvas

**JavaScript:**

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $(".photos").each(function(i){                      
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            alert($(this).val());
            var image = new Image();
                var foto = $(".photos").val();                         
                image.src =  $(".photos").val();
                image.onload = function(){ 
                    //var foto = $(".photos").val();                         
                    //image.src =  $(".photos").val();
                     $(".canvas").each(function(i){
                         var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")[i].getContext('2d');
                         ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, 320, 240); 
                     });                        
                }                   
        }
    });                     
});
```

**CitizenList.jsp**:

```
<title>Citizen Search Results</title>
 </head>
  <body>
   <c:forEach items="${citizens}" var="citizen">
    <div><p><canvas class="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas></div>
        First name:- ${citizen.fName} , Last Name:- ${citizen.lName}
        <input type="text" value="${citizen.photo}" class="photos"/>
    </c:forEach>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What does [tag:fancybox] have to do with it (I don't see if referenced in the code).

Comment: sorry i modified the question but forgot to remove the tag my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image source needed to reference `$(this).val()`. There was no need to iterate through each canvas however just needed to use the index to move to the current canvas. Under is the completed solution:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".photos").each(function(i){                      
                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                       var image = new Image();                      
                        image.src =  $(this).val();

                        image.onload = function(){ 
                                 var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")[i].getContext('2d');
                                 ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, 320, 240); 
                         }               
                }
            });                     
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your `photo` input box being created multiple times with one id.

```
<input type="text" id="photo" value="${citizen.photo}"/>
```

Inside of a `foreach`.

```
<c:forEach items="${citizens}" var="citizen">
```

Which will render html like this:

```
<div><p><canvas id="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas></div>
    First name:-Jim , Last Name:- Doe
    <input type="text" id="photo" value="xyz"/>

<div><p><canvas id="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas></div>
    First name:- Bob , Last Name:- Doe
    <input type="text" id="photo" value="abc"/>
```

And of course your jQuery lookup `$("#photo")` only matches the first one.

---

Instead you can give them a class and iterate over them:

```
<input type="text" id="photo${status.id}" class="photo" value="${citizen.photo}"/>
```

And iterate over them with jQuery foreach

```
$('.photo').each(function(){ //..
```

Comment: if i remove the id on $("#photo") how can i look up its value to draw on the canvas?

Comment: I updated the question with my modified code but the image is'nt drawing any suggestions?